# Can casting the Meld into Stone spell before I hit the ground save me from falling damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, falling

If I am falling a great height and manage to cast *meld into stone* before hitting the ground (which happens to be stone, such as a cavern floor), would I suffer falling damage?

Consider the fall to be a great enough height that I can take an action during the fall. I was thinking that I could simply cast it during the fall and the spell would take effect upon impact.

Comment: Related: [How would using Thunderwave to stop falling damage work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98320/how-would-using-thunderwave-to-stop-falling-damage-work), [Can Earthbind be used for a Feather Fall type effect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116059/can-earthbind-be-used-for-a-feather-fall-type-effect), [If you misty step 30 feet straight up do you have time to attack a foe next to you before you start falling?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123403/if-you-misty-step-30-feet-straight-up-do-you-have-time-to-attack-a-foe-next-to-y)

Comment: Im not crazy about the rule in Xanathar's book (500 ft per turn immediately) I base it on distance vs acceleration to account for time falling. Avg at 200 ft per turn increasing up to maybe 600. Starting as low as 60 ft. Dmg being 1d6 bludgeoning dmg per 10 ft to a max of 20d6. But the real meat of my issue is, would meld to stone eliminate impact damage? What would happen to the body as a result of all that momentum? Granting that given an appropriate amount of falling time, the spell can be cast and that upon "contact" with the ground the faller would meld with stone, but what then?

Answer (score 4):

## No, it won't save you

From the [Meld Into Stone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/meld-into-stone) spell description:

> You **step into** a stone object or surface large enough to fully contain
> your body, melding yourself and all the equipment you carry with the
> stone for the duration. Using your movement, you **step into** the stone
> at a point you can touch.

Falling isn't stepping, so I wouldn't say it's an appropriate interpretation of the description of the spell.